# python list sort

Tags: python, sorting

I have got a list i.e.

```
ls= [u'Cancer',u"Men's",u'Orthopedics',u'Pediatric',u"Senior's",u"Women's"]
```

ls.sort() does not seem to work here due to presence of single quote in the list elements.

I need to sort this list. Any idea???

Comment: Your list is already sorted, and `ls.sort()` simply leaves it unchanged, as expected.  What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by `does not seem to work`:  if it's not the order that you expect, show us what order you got!

Comment: One common pitfall with list.sort" for beginners is that it does not return anything (actually, returns "None") - so, doing `sortedlist = mylist.sort()` does not work in any case. Use the builtin sorted if you need a copy of the list, like in: `sortedlist = sorted(mylist)`

Comment: Sorry mate I must be drunk... I need to remove this question. both of you are correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, the question *is* valid and the answer is not exactly correct in **general case**.
If the test material *was not* already sorted, it would not get correctly alphabetized but the `'`s would cause the list to be sorted to wrong order:

```
>>> l = ["'''b", "a", "a'ab", "aaa"]
>>> l.sort()
>>> l
["'''b", 'a', "a'ab", 'aaa']
>>> from functools import partial
>>> import string
>>> keyfunc = partial(string.replace, old="'", new="")
>>> l.sort(key=keyfunc)
>>> l
['a', 'aaa', "a'ab", "'''b"]
```

Comment: If you refer to my answer as not being exactly correct, could you please clarify what exactly isn't correct?

Comment: kimvais is right..his explanation is more accurate..thanks man

Comment: @user1170364: Please reconsider.  This answer says "the `'`s would cause the list to be sorted to wrong order", which simply is not true.  The truth is that `'` is sorted before all alphanumeric characters, which isn't "wrong", but might not be what you want in some given context.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> ls
[u'Cancer', u"Men's", u'Orthopedics', u'Pediatric', u"Senior's", u"Women's"]
>>> ls.sort()
>>> ls
[u'Cancer', u"Men's", u'Orthopedics', u'Pediatric', u"Senior's", u"Women's"]
```

Since the list was sorted in the first place, it didn't change. `sort` has no problem with `'` - but note that it sorts before the *a-z* and *A-Z* characters:

```
>>> ls
[u'abc', u'abz', u"ab'"]
>>> ls.sort()
>>> ls
[u"ab'", u'abc', u'abz']
>>>
```

Comment: You can ignore case in sorting by `import string` and `ls.sort(key=string.lower)`

Comment: This is correct in this exact case, but not generally. @EliBendersky see my example, for example `["a'b", "aa"]` won't get correctly _alphabetically_ sorted without a `key` function.

Comment: @Kimvais: I truly don't understand what you mean, but hey, if the OP found in your answer what he needed, I don't mind! Good for him.

Comment: what I mean is that `aa'b` being _before_ `aaa` is _not in __alphabetically__ correct order_